# play framework 2.3 classnotfound using play-hikaricp

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator, hikaricp

I keep getting the following stack trace when I try to configure my Play 2.3 application to use hikaricp

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
 com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PoolUtilities.createInstance(PoolUtilities.java:105)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeDataSource(HikariPool.java:518)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:137)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:102)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
 com.edulify.play.hikaricp.HirakiCPDBApi$$anonfun$1.apply(HirakiCPDBApi.scala:36)
 com.edulify.play.hikaricp.HirakiCPDBApi$$anonfun$1.apply(HirakiCPDBApi.scala:32)
 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
 scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:79)
 scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
 scala.collection.AbstractSet.scala$collection$SetLike$$super$map(Set.scala:47)
 scala.collection.SetLike$class.map(SetLike.scala:92)
 scala.collection.AbstractSet.map(Set.scala:47)
```

my build.sbt includes the mysql-connector and it should be in the classpath

```
name := """myapp"""

version := "2.3-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += Resolver.url("Edulify Repository", url("http://edulify.github.io/modules/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaCore,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
    javaJdbc,
    "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.13",
    "com.lowagie" % "itext" % "2.1.7",
    "net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports" % "5.2.0",
    "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
    javaEbean,
    cache,
    javaWs,
    "com.edulify" %% "play-hikaricp" % "1.4.1"
)
```

also here is my conf/play.plugins file:

`200:com.edulify.play.hikaricp.HikariCPPlugin`

Any help would be appreciated

~Nick

Comment: can you please share your conf file. the place where you have defined `dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` Try removing double or single quotes if any..

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened to me I think in hikaricp.prod.properties file you provide
jdbcUrl = "***JDBC_CONNECTION***" **remove quotes** solved the problem 
jdbcUrl  = JDBC_CO